# How do I handle time zones?

Tags: sql-server

We have a process which runs on the local time to retrieve the data in SQL, however we have to convert that local time to CST time to make it more server friendly.

Is there a way that we can put in the local time zone only and the server converts that time to CST time and perform the job when the converted time matches the desired time?

Comment: Handling the timezone conversion should be done in application, not SQL Server. You'll also need to ensure that when storing your data you either use `datetimeoffset`, which stores the timezone data along side your datetime, or ensure **all** datetimes stored in your database are UTC times. If you don't do either of these, then you have no reliable way of converting the values correctly.

Comment: Hi Lamu, thanks for your feedback.

We have to pull the data from a webservice which published the data on certain local time (which can vary and notified). I would like application to convert the local time zone to server time (which is in Dallas), rather than converting the local time zone manually. Hope it will clear the cluster. :)

Comment: So, I ***assume*** the webservice is telling SQL Server what the time zone of that time is and, therefore, you're storing your data as a `datetimeoffset`? If so, then you know what the value of the time is, so you can then apply relevant conversion to "Dallas time" (which changes based on DST) in the application. (also, there is no M in my alias).

Comment: If, however, the webservice is **not** telling you the timezone of the time, then it is (in effect) useless to you. If I gave you the date and time `'2019-04-09T17:34:59.017'` would you know what time that was in Dallas without the Timezone data?

Comment: SQL Server has rather awkward support for time zones in the `DATETIMEOFFSET` types, the `SWITCHOFFSET` function and the `AT TIME ZONE` clause (as well as `TZOFFSET` for `DATEPART`). If you really insist on converting times within SQL Server (rather than keeping everything in UTC and letting the clients take care of it) some combination of these can usually get you what you want, but the resulting expressions are almost never pretty. (Nor efficient for things like index lookups.)

Comment: I agree with @JeroenMostert here. If you are getting timezone data (from the webserverice), It would be better to use SQL Server to translate that to UTC. Then pass the UTC time to the application to convert to "Dallas" time. You could convert the value (as it arrives) to `UTC` by doing `{Your datetimeoffset value} AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`